# NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'home' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Tags: python, django, testing

I do not have any view name called home in my app. I've verified all other third party apps I use, NONE of them have a 'home' in their url conf.

Yet, this line of code in my tests.py spits out the error in the title (see code comments): [See Full traceback too](http://pastebin.com/0bF11SuR)

```
# the test section where error comes
def test_add_item_with_login(self):
    ''' See if will post if user login'''
    self._create_user_and_login()

    response = self.client.post(reverse('add'), self.post_data)
    print response
    # this above line give me:
    # ..Vary: Cookie
    # X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
    # Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    # Location: http://testserver/detail/00000/

    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
    # this line above doesn't fail, kinda ambiguous
    # if post succeeded, and redirected to location above, I expect it to fail because new page should give 200?

    print resolve('/detail/00000/')
    # the above gives: 
    # ResolverMatch(func=main.views.imei_detail, args=(), kwargs={'slug': u'00000'}, url_name=detail, app_name=None, namespaces=[])

    # the next line is the referenced point of the error
    response = self.client.get('/detail/00000/')
```

again, I do not have any part in any urlconf in my entire project with even the word 'home' in it.

I've gone through my templates, .html by .html (along with their includes) and **none** has a reference to a url called 'home'

Thus, where is the 'home' coming from? Is the test suite using a urlconf I don't know of?

Comment: You're posting to the "add" view. That's presumably redirecting somewhere, probably "home". Post the code of that view.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Okay, I'll post the view in a couple of hours time. Not behind PC now. But the add has a CreateView which upon adding an object, by default redirects to the detail page of the created object. That's what the add view actually does in the browser, so maybe the test suite does its own thing?

Comment: My mistake, the error is coming in the get of detail/0000, at the end. It's that view and template you should post.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Lightbulb! I'll look again at the detail page. Will update you when I do. Thanks